# Python function call as return value scoping

Tags: python

```
def biggest(aDict):
    if aDict.values() == []  :
        return None

    lengths =[]
    for e in aDict:
        lengths.append(len(aDict[e]))

    return max(lenghts)
```

`biggest({'U': []})` or anything else produces the error:

```
NameError: global name 'lenghts' is not defined
```

lenghts is defined in my function , so can you help me with this?

Comment: +1 for dislexia! I would have fallen also.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've got `return max(lenghts)` and your variable is called `lengths` ?

Comment: OMG! typos can hide in front of your eyes, was looking at the code for over 5 mins and didnt see it.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a spelling mistake.

`lengths` and `lenghts` are different.

Answer (score 1):

Python interpreter looks for a variable in enclosing scopes - when it does not find local - till it reaches global scope.

Failing to find **lenghts** - due to typo, it should have been **lengths** - it starts looking for it in the global scope. Failing to find it, it reports that it was not found in the global scope - implying that it failed to find it in the local scope too.

And here is more compact - and less error-prone (less variables to misspell) - variant of your function:

```
def biggest(aDict):
    if not aDict:
        return None
    return max(len(val) for val in aDict.values())
```